# How to differentiate Full Users and Team Members using REST API (MS GRAPH or WEB API)?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I need to figure out which user is "Full User" or "Team Member". Could not find any information in the documentation. Can someone help me?

Comment: It is not clear to understand.. explain a bit more with some screenshot or code to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Microsoft Graph REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview).

You could call [users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list) method to get a list of users.

**Request**

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 608

{
  "value": [
    {
      "businessPhones": [
        "businessPhones-value"
      ],
      "displayName": "displayName-value",
      "givenName": "givenName-value",
      "jobTitle": "jobTitle-value",
      "mail": "mail-value",
      "mobilePhone": "mobilePhone-value",
      "officeLocation": "officeLocation-value",
      "preferredLanguage": "preferredLanguage-value",
      "surname": "surname-value",
      "userPrincipalName": "userPrincipalName-value",
      "id": "id-value"
    }
  ]
}
```

You could then iterate through the list of users and get each of their license details using the [licenseDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-licensedetails) method.

**Request**

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{userid}/licenseDetails`

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 389

{
  "value": [
    {
      "servicePlans": [
        {
          "servicePlanId": "servicePlanId-value",
          "servicePlanName": "servicePlanName-value",
          "provisioningStatus": "provisioningStatus-value",
          "appliesTo": "appliesTo-value"
        }
      ],
      "skuId": "skuId-value",
      "skuPartNumber": "skuPartNumber-value",
      "id": "id-value"
    }
  ]
}
```